# Server error - Is it from my host provider side or sytax error?

Tags: server, error

I get this error message:

> **Server error**
>
> The website encountered an error while
>   retrieving `http://mywebsite.com/`. It
>   may be down for maintenance or
>   configured incorrectly. Here are some
>   suggestions: Reload this web page
>   later.

Is it from my host provider internal server error, or my website sytax error? 
How do I investigate the problem?

Comment: Looks like a web browser error message - can you access the server hosting your site by IP address?

Comment: @danlefree I think my host service provider using a shared public IP. i get `Website Not Located` page when i try to access by IP address.

Comment: If your server is down, it says unable to connect. So it must be a 500 Internal Server Error which is mostly because of bad htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you get when the server returns an HTTP code 500. Your browser sees that and displays a more friendly message. So it's an internal server error.

To investigate the problem you need to let us know a bit more information - has it ever worked? Did you change something recently? If nothing has changed and this has suddenly started happening then I'd contact your hosting company.

Comment: If nothing works, not even a plain HTML page then it's a problem at their end and I think you need to contact their support line.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to apache logs on that server? If you do check your error.log and you will have the answer ;) Usually it's in `/var/log/apache2`.